# How to insert values in next couple of rows based on the previous row

Tags: mysql, sql, r

I have a table like this

```
  Id   A    B     
  1  11   event1  
  2  12   event2   
  3  00   event1
  4  00   event2
  5  11   event1
  6  00   event2
  7  00   event3
  8  13   event1
```

I want to change 00 from the previous values. The output will look like this

```
  Id  A   B 
  1  11   event1
  2  12   event2
  3  12   event1
  4  12   event2
  5  11   event1
  6  11   event2
  7  11   event3
  8  13   event1
```

Is there a way to do this in R or MySQL.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is a one-liner to do this in R. Basically, we replace 0s with `NA` and use `zoo::na.locf()` to fill with the last non-NA value, i.e.

```
transform(d1, A = zoo::na.locf(replace(A, A == 0, NA)))
```

which gives,

> ```
>   Id  A      B
> 1  1 11 event1
> 2  2 12 event2
> 3  3 12 event1
> 4  4 12 event2
> 5  5 11 event1
> 6  6 11 event2
> 7  7 11 event3
> 8  8 13 event1
> ```

As @G. Grothendieck notes, your `A` variable seems to be a character. If that's the case then,

```
transform(d1, A = na.locf0(replace(A, A == "00", NA)))
```

Comment: It's not jiust that `A` is character but also that `na.locf0` applied to a vector will ensure that the result is the same length as the input.  Also we only need to apply it to `A` and not the entire data.frame.

Comment: Ahh...right. I did not even notice that I apply it on the whole data frame. Also about `na.locf0` ,..., when does `na.locf` produce a result with different length than the input?

Comment: If there are leading NAs then `na.locf` will drop them unless `na.rm = FALSE` is used.  `na.locf0` hard codes to `na.rm = FALSE` but only works on vectors.  `na.locf` was really developed for zoo objects where you usually don't need filling but if you want to apply it to a data.frame where filling is normally needed then you have to worry about such things.

Comment: Oh, I get it. Great. Thank you for the info @G.Grothendieck

Answer (score 1):

You can use *correlated* subquery in MySQL :

```
SELECT t.id, 
       (CASE WHEN A <> '00' 
             THEN A
             ELSE (SELECT t1.A
                   FROM table t1
                   WHERE t1.id < t.id AND t1.A <> '00'
                   ORDER BY t1.id DESC
                   LIMIT 1
                  )
        END) AS A, B
FROM table t;
```

Comment: Is there a more optimized way to do it. I am running it on 80 M rows and it's taking forever to run. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In `R` you can do this with the `tidyr` function `fill`.  First change all the 0 to NA with `mutate`, then the fill function will replace it with the last value.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% mutate(A = ifelse(A==0,NA,A)) %>% fill(A)
#  Id  A      B
#1  1 11 event1
#2  2 12 event2
#3  3 12 event1
#4  4 12 event2
#5  5 11 event1
#6  6 11 event2
#7  7 11 event3
#8  8 13 event1
```